# MySQL Query Won't Add User Input to Table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I created a 'Create a Profile' form that includes a username and password entry for a user to sign up. I've set my code to retrieve the value of all form fields. I am testing to see if the first name updates to my database, and it does not. The message that I set for failed query execution shows up when I submit the form: 'Error querying request'. I'm connected to the database properly and have tried reformatting my query string (with the variable with quotes and with out quotes):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO employees(firstName) VALUES ('$first_name')";
```

I would appreciate any input as to why the query string is not executing properly. Counld it be an issue with the formatting or variables?

Here is my code (purposely blanked out the values):

```
<?php

    define('DB_LOCATION', 'x');
    define('DB_USERNAME', 'x');
    define('DB_PASS', 'x');
    define('DB_NAME', 'x');

    $dbc = 0;

    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_LOCATION, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASS, DB_NAME)
        or die('Error connecting to database');

if(isset($_POST['submit']))  { 

    $first_name = $_POST['first'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last'];
    $email_address = $_POST['email_address'];
    $user_name = $_POST['user'];
    $user_password = $_POST['pass'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO employees(firstName) VALUES ('$first_name')";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
        or die('Error querying request');

        echo '<p>Congrats, your name has been added to the database</p>';


    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title></title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="5_Signup_CSS.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="formFormat">
<form name="signupForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<table class="tableFormat">
  <tr>Create an Account</tr>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="first" name="first" value ="<?php echo $first_name ?>"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="last" name="last" value="<?php echo $last_name ?>" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" id="email_address" name="email_address" value="<?php echo $email_address ?>" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" id="user" name="user" value="<?php echo $user_name?>" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td><td><input type="text" id="pass" name="pass" value="<?php echo $user_password?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" /></td>
    </tr>

</table>
</form>
</div>


<?php
    mysqli_close($dbc);
?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try calling `echo mysqli_error();` after your call of `mysqli_query()`. This will echo the last MySQL error and give you more info about what exactly went wrong. More infos about the function: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Another case of bobby tables.. https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 1):

<del>One issue that I can see is that you are inserting the $firstname value as literally "$first_name".

You will want to change it to `('".$first_name."')`

`$query = "INSERT INTO employees(firstName) VALUES ('$first_name')";`</del>

You may also want to check your table names depending on what exactly the error is that you are getting.

Also you do not need to define $dbc before calling the mysqli_connect.

Also you may want to look at changing from mysqli to PDO. From my experience PDO is much easier to use.

Edit: Errors
You may want to wrap all of your slq queries in a try catch statement, that way you can catch all exceptions that are thrown and then decide how to display them

[PHP Try / Catch](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up with the format of the values. I've updated it and I'm still getting the same error, so I'm thinking now that it might be only a connection error. Thanks again.

Comment: I added a link to the php docs for try/catch in my edit, it should let you pull all expectations that are happening whether its a mysqli error or something else.

Comment: The statement about the `$firstname` variable is incorrect. As a double quoted string, the variable will be parsed: https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: @Ben thanks, i just saw the single quotes and didn't think it all the way through.